# How can i connect to Spring Security without a login form

Tags: angularjs, spring, web-services, spring-security, spring-boot

I created a Rest API with Spring Boot and secured with Spring Security, i am using this API in the client side with AngularJS running inside a Xampp server.

The question is, how can i avoid the Spring Security login form and make users login without being redirected to the login form, using a REST call for example like:

> http://server-url:8080/login?username=user&password=pass

Use case: if i need to call my API from a Desktop application